# Laravel can't connect to DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm following through the [Quick Start Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#displaying-data), and got to the section actually connecting to the DB to fetch the users table, and am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My `database.php` includes the following setup (default set to mysql):

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'bt',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

When I go to the terminal window, however, I'm able to log in using `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` then just hit enter to go in without a password, which I thought would be equivalent (the 'bt' table shows up when I run `show databases();`). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the solution :)

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
    'database'  => 'bt',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefi
```

Comment: And here I always thought those two were the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it takes me all night long to find where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that pdo is not installed on your machine.
You can check if it's installed from the phpinfo() page or a php script

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo') ) {
    .......
}
```

On linux you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```